# Convert two 16 Bit Registers to 32 Bit float value flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart, modbus, uint16

I am using a Modbus flutter lib, reading 2 registers I obtain:

[16177, 4660] I need a function to convert it to a 32 bit float value: 0.7

I found this function

```
ByteBuffer buffer = new Uint16List.fromList(fileBytes).buffer;
ByteData byteData = new ByteData.view(buffer);
double x = byteData.getFloat32(0);
```

It says 0.000045747037802357227 swap byte value

Can you help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always find it easiest to start with the byte array and insert stuff into that. What's happening is that your code is defaulting to the native endianness (apparently `little`) but you need to be doing this in big endianness.

Here's an overly verbose solution that you can cut out the print statements (and hex codec)

```
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:convert/convert.dart'; // only needed for debugging

void main() {
  final registers = [16177, 4660];
  final bytes = Uint8List(4); // start with the 4 bytes = 32 bits

  var byteData = bytes.buffer.asByteData(); // ByteData lets you choose the endianness
  byteData.setInt16(0, registers[0], Endian.big); // Note big is the default here, but shown for completeness
  byteData.setInt16(2, registers[1], Endian.big);
  print(bytes); // just for debugging - does my byte order look right?
  print(hex.encode(bytes)); // ditto

  final f32 = byteData.getFloat32(0, Endian.big);
  print(f32);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help I found another method

  _val= [16177, 4660];
   Uint16List intBytes = Uint16List.fromList(_val.reversed.toList());
    List<double> floatList = intBytes.buffer.asFloat32List();
    print(floatList);

Comment: @TuceT yes, that will work, but *only* on a little endian architecture. The above code will work on either.